# como eu faço para criar uma função no vbs que ao clicar no enter ele alterna duas janelas ou seja alt + tab

Tags: vbs

esse é o codigo que estou usando

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

set Window = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Window.RegisterAsBrowser = True
Window.MenuBar = True
Window.ToolBar = True
Window.AddressBar = True
Window.StatusBar = True
Window.FullScreen = False
Window.Resizable = True
Window.Visible = True
Window.Width = 850
Window.Height = 720




Window.Navigate("www.microsoft.com")

wscript.sleep 5000

Window.Navigate2 "www.globo.com",navflags

'while 1<>2

if objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" then
    wscript.sleep 2000
    objShell.SendKeys "^{TAB}"

end if

'wend
```

Está dando erro no if. Alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Não me parece que o método SendKey retorna alguma coisa pra ser  usado no IF como você está fazendo. Retire o IF fora que deve funcionar.

Comment: como faço para executar o ^{TAB} só quando clicar no enter?

Comment: você precisa capturar o evento que ocorre quando o usuário pressiona a tecla enter. Dentro dessa rotina, você executa o TAB. Entretanto, é preciso ver se há como fazer isso via VBS.

Answer (score -3):

Não conheço codigo no vbsScript que captura tecla: Eu consegui o efeito que você quer me página web em javaScript:

```
<html>
<body>



<script>

var cont=true;

function keyPressed(evt){
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var key = evt.keyCode || evt.which;

return key;

}


document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    var str = keyPressed(evt);

    if(str==13){
if (cont){ 
    cont=false
    window.open('https://www.horadecodar.com.br', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');

    }else{
    window.open('https://www.google.com.br', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
cont=true
}
}


};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```